# Functions when dealing with derivatives - thinking about it wrong?

Tags: calculus, functions, derivatives

I just came to a realization that my entire view of how functions work might not be completely sound. I'll explain:

Coming from more of a CS background, I see functions $f(x)$ as an example, as taking some input, "storing" it in $x$, substituting this new value wherever $x$ comes up, and produces one output.

However, I was thinking about this in the context of the derivative.

Let's say we define the following functions:

$f(x) = x^2$

$g(x) = \frac{d}{dx}f(x)$

I'd wish to evaluate the derivative at $a$. If I do $g(a)$, my mind would think that it substitutes every instance of $x$ with $a$, which would result in:

$g(a) = \frac{d}{dx}f(a)$

$g(a) = 0$

This is not what happens. We instead get the derivative evaluated at point a, so $g'(a)$. So where is my reasoning wrong? It seems to be the only exception I can find where plugging in value doesn't result in same answer.

Comment: Your function $g(x)$ takes in a _function_ as an input. So you really should write it as $g(f(x)) = \frac{d}{dx} f(x)$

Comment: If you'd written $g(a) = \frac{df}{dx} (a)$ you'd be okay. (The $\frac{dy}{dx}$ notation is awful in some contexts.)

Comment: Take into account that the computation of the derivative at $a$ requires using the values of $f$ in a whole neighborhood of $a$, not only the value at $a$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$g(a) = \frac{d}{dx}f(a)=0$ is wrong because it is the consequence of the misunderstanding of an ambiguous symbolism.

Come back to $\quad g(x) = \frac{d\,f(x)}{dx}$ . If fact, that is a contraction of :
$$g(x) = \left(\frac{d\,f(t)}{dt}\right)_{t=x} \quad \text{where }t\text{ is a dummy variable.}$$
This means that in a first step the function is differentiated, then in a second step the resulting function is taken at the value $x$.

Thus,$\quad g(a) \neq \frac{d\,f(a)}{dx}=0\quad$, but :
$$g(a) = \left(\frac{d\,f(t)}{dt}\right)_{t=a}$$
which, of course, isn't null in general.

Answer (score 0):

Since you come from a computer science background, probably this explanation makes more sense to you. Consider this pseudo-code:

`def f(x:Real_Number): Real_Number {
   return f(x)
}`

This describes your $f(x)$.

`def g(x:Function): Function {
  return derivative(f)
}`

This describes your $g(x)$.

Comment: Thanks! This does help. So when you're evaluating at a point, how would that play into the analogy?

Comment: `val df = g(f)`, then `val result = df(a)`.

Comment: @rb612 The point is, when we talk about a function $f$, we have to know from which set the function maps into which set. Namely, if we have $f:A\to B$, we have to know what $A$ and $B$ are.